# Using multiple lightboxes on the same List causing problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
// Open the Modal
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

// Close the Modal
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
/*Main list*/
#list ul{width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:0px;  list-style-type:none; margin:5% 0% 0% 0%; overflow:hidden; padding:0% 0% 4% 0%; background:rgba(240,240,240,1);}
#list li{box-shadow:0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); transition:0.1s; border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px; border:2px solid black; color:black; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); width:70%; height:auto; display:block; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-size:0.9vw; margin:0% 0% 5% 0%; overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-all; word-break:break-word; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; text-align:center; line-height:1.2; }

.row > .column {
 Padding:0%; margin:0;
  width:30%; height:auto; float:left;
}

.column img{width:95%; height:auto; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left;}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to eachother */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Caption text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}


.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li>
 <!-- Images used to open the lightbox -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  Some text
</div>

<!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
</div> 
</li>

<li>
 <!-- Images used to open the lightbox -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  Some text
</div>

<!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>



   
  </div>
</div> 
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have a ul which contains multiple li and each li has a main image. 
Once the user clicks on the image, a lightbox opens for the user.
I've implemented the example found on W3C Schools and it works very well. 
Except for one important thing: 
When I click on the image on my second li, it shows the content of my first li. 
How can I separate the content on a large number of list items without having to change the id/class?

Answer (score 0):

The example you used is made for one slider. When you tried to duplicate, you duplicated the element id "myModal" which you should not do. ID's are meant to be unique.

Likewise, the javascript functions were written to act on one modal with that ID. So one way to fix this is to re-write the functions to pass the modal ID. That way the functions can manipulate the correct slider block. Here is an example:

```js
 // Open the Modal
function openModal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

// Close the Modal
function closeModal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides('myModal', slideIndex);
showSlides('myModal2', slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(id, n) {
  showSlides(id, slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(id, n) {
  showSlides(id, slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(id, n) {
  var i;
  var modalDiv = document.getElementById(id);
  var slides = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
/*   var dots = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("demo"); */
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
/*   for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  } */
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
/*   dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active"; */
}
```

```css
/*Main list*/
#list ul{width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:0px;  list-style-type:none; margin:5% 0% 0% 0%; overflow:hidden; padding:0% 0% 4% 0%; background:rgba(240,240,240,1);}
#list li{box-shadow:0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); transition:0.1s; border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px; border:2px solid black; color:black; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); width:70%; height:auto; display:block; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-size:0.9vw; margin:0% 0% 5% 0%; overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-all; word-break:break-word; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; text-align:center; line-height:1.2; }

.row > .column {
 Padding:0%; margin:0;
  width:30%; height:auto; float:left;
}

.column img{width:95%; height:auto; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left;}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to eachother */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Caption text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}


.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li>
 <!-- Images used to open the lightbox -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" onclick="openModal('myModal');currentSlide('myModal',1)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  Some text
</div>

<!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal')">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides('myModal',-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides('myModal',1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
</div> 
</li>

<li>
 <!-- Images used to open the lightbox -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" onclick="openModal('myModal2');currentSlide('myModal',1)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  Some text
</div>

<!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal2')">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides('myModal2',-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides('myModal2',1)">&#10095;</a>



   
  </div>
</div> 
</li>
</ul>
</div>
 
 <script>

</script>
```

Comment: The example seems to be working. However, my page will have a large number of LIs with images. So in that case I have to distinguish each LI with an ID. I'd like to avoid that if possible. To clarify: Let's say one page has a UL with 100 LIs and each LI has about five images. I basically have to have 100 IDs for each LI to distinguish it from other LIs. Is there any other solution that does not involve IDs/Classes?